# How to avoid name error in ms access formula?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I want to set DefaultValue of a form field to

```
=IIf(IsNull([Forms]![MyForm]![MySubForm].[Form]![MyField]);"";[Forms]![MyForm]![MySubForm].[Form]![MyField])
```

When MyForm is closed I want to set the field value to "". Unfortunately I can't find how to test if MyForm is closed or not : I have tried IsNull, IsObject, very Is it always return #Name?

Is this possible ?

Comment: I recommend you use VBA to set the default instead of using the statement you have above. Avoid IIF's as much as possible.

Comment: Sure but I'd still like to know if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a function like this to check to see if a form is open:

```
Function IsLoaded(ByVal strFormName As String) As Boolean
 ' Returns True if the specified form is open in Form view or Datasheet view.

    Const conObjStateClosed = 0
    Const conDesignView = 0

    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, strFormName) <> conObjStateClosed Then
        If Forms(strFormName).CurrentView <> conDesignView Then
            IsLoaded = True
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I think there's no other choice than create such function.

Comment: Doesn't work either but seems the problem comes from iff function rather.